# request for member which is of non-class type using .empty or .size

Tags: c++

First I apologize for the formatting this is my first time posting on this website. Below is the beginning of my program which is just a simple menu that has different sorts and searches and ways of creating a list. My error lies in the menu method when I try to use .empty on my items list. I get the error request for member which is of non class type. I'm only in my 2nd year of programming so try to explain like I'm an idiot lol.

```
const int MLS = 50;

typedef int element;

const element SENTINEL = -1;

element read_element();

int read_int();

class AList{ 

        private:
                element items[MLS];
                int size;
                void Swap(int pos1, int pos2);
                bool sorted;
        public:
                void Read();
                void GenerateRandomList();
                void Print();
                void BubbleSort();
                void InsertionSort();
                void SelectionSort();
                void LinearSearch(element target);
                void BinarySearch(element target);
                void Menu();
};

int main(){

  AList A;

        A.Menu();
}


void AList::Menu(){

        int choice;
        element target;


        cout << "Current list: ";
        if (items.empty == true)
                cout << "(empty)";
        else
                Print();
        if (sorted == true)
                cout << "(KNOWN to be ordered)" << endl << endl;
        else
                cout << "(NOT KNOWN to be ordered)" << endl << endl;

        cout << "Actions:" << endl;
        cout << "       1. Reset the current list from the keyboard" << endl;
        cout << "       2. Reset the current list using randomly generated ";
```

Comment: Please format you code properly. You can find help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Regardless of being new here, there are 13.6 million existing questions you can use to see what questions ought to look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
typedef int element;
...
class AList {
    element items[MLS];
    ...
};
...
void AList::Menu() {
    ...
    if (items.empty == true)
        ...
    ...
}
```

As you can see, `items` is just an array of `int`s. However, in c++, arrays have neither named members (such as java's `arr.length`) nor methods associated with them. If you want this functionality in your code, I recommend you use [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, `items` is just an array of `element`. In C++ arrays don't have any methods/properties. It's just aligned data without any logic. Consider using `vector` instead.

edit: change

```
element items[MLS]
```

to

```
vector<element> items
```

You will be able to use `items.empty()` or `items.size()` You won,t need to set an initial size of 50, the vector will resize itself whenever its needed.

Comment: how exactly would i go about doing that?